# SpringBootでの画面単位の権限制御

Tags: java, spring-boot

「やりたい事」
・Springbootを使用した複数画面で構成されたWebアプリにて、画面単位に権限制御を行いたいです。

・下記、参考サイトのようなロールベースを画面毎に制御したいです。
下記、参考サイトだとアプリ内全画面に適用となる認識です。

https://qiita.com/suke_masa/items/1473450a8b59eea5f3cd

どなたか知見ありましたら
アドバイスお願いします。

Comment: [Multiple HttpSecurity Instances](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity_instances) にあるように、画面ごと(URLパスごと)に `SecurityFilterChain` Bean を定義・登録することになるかと思います。

Comment: 出羽様　ありがとうございます。ご指定の方法でコード書いてみます！